# How to create a table shows frequency of all dummy variables in r

Tags: r, frequency, dummy-variable

I am a rookie in R.
I want to create a frequency table of all dummy variables and I have a data like this

```
ID Dummy_2008 Dummy_2009 Dummy_2010 Dummy_2011 Dummy_2012 Dummy_2013
1  1          1          0          0          1          1
2  0          0          1          1          0          1
3  0          0          1          0          0          1
4  0          1          1          0          0          1
5  0          0          0          0          1          0
6  0          0          0          1          0          0
```

I want to see how total frequency in each variable like this

```
            0    1   sum
Dummy_2008  5    1   6
Dummy_2009  4    2   6
Dummy_2010  3    3   6
Dummy_2011  4    2   6
Dummy_2012  4    2   6
Dummy_2013  2    4   6
```

I only know to use table() , but I can only do this one variable a time.
I have many time serious dummy variables, and I want to see the trend of them.

Many thanks for the help
Terence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option using `mtabulate` and `addmargins`

```
library(qdapTools)
addmargins(as.matrix(mtabulate(df1[-1])),2)
#           0 1 Sum
#Dummy_2008 5 1   6
#Dummy_2009 4 2   6
#Dummy_2010 3 3   6
#Dummy_2011 4 2   6
#Dummy_2012 4 2   6
#Dummy_2013 2 4   6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = as.data.frame(t(sapply(dat[,-1], table)))        
result$Sum = rowSums(result)

           0 1 Sum
Dummy_2008 5 1   6
Dummy_2009 4 2   6
Dummy_2010 3 3   6
Dummy_2011 4 2   6
Dummy_2012 4 2   6
Dummy_2013 2 4   6
```

Explanation:

`sapply` applies a function to each column of a data frame and returns a matrix. So `sapply(dat[,-1], table)` returns a matrix with the output of `table` for each column (except the first column, which we've excluded).

The matrix needs to be transposed so that the column names from the original data frame are the rows and the dummy values are the columns, so we use the `t` (transpose) function for that.

We want a data frame, not a matrix, so we wrap the whole thing in `as.data.frame`.

Next, we want another column giving the total number of values, so we use the `rowSums` function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help. But it hows "Error in rowSums(result) : 'x' must be numeric", I am still looking for where is wrong.

Comment: The error is telling you that a least one of the columns is not numeric. `str(result)` will show you the class of each column. I'm not sure why that would happen with `table`, but hard to say more without more information on your data and code.

Comment: Thank you so much. I change your code a little and I get what I want, although without sum.

"result1 = as.data.frame(sapply(dat[,-1], table))
result1_1=(t(result1)([-3,][-4,][-5,][-6,][-7,][-8,]))
result1_1"
Thank you very much.^^